# Turn off wireless after a wireless disconnect

Tags: gratis, android, wireless

When using my phone at home, I connect via wireless (WLAN). However, I often forget to turn off wireless when I leave my house.

Due to battery and security reasons, I'd like to have my wireless turned off when the connection is lost. Ideally the time is configurable, e.g. turn off wireless after 3 minutes of lost connection.

It's totally ok that I have to turn it on manually when I'm back home. That's what I do today as well. I don't want a GPS-based solution due to battery concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at my list of apps for [WiFi Automatisation](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation), it seems **[Smart WiFi Toggler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebouh00.smartwifitoggler)** is a good candidate for you:

- turns WiFi off when not connected to a network
- turns WiFi on when a known hotspot is present
- constantly learns where your hotspots are located to make its decisions
- Uses your network location. No GPS battery drain.

[image: Smart WiFi] [image: Smart WiFi] [image: Smart WiFi]
<sup>*Smart WiFi Toggler* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebouh00.smartwifitoggler); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As you can see by the first two screenshots, the app uses CellIDs for location – which means no extra drain, not even for network (would work with mobile data disabled even), as your phone knows the connected cell anyway (needed for calls).

I'm not using this myself (I rather use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) which can do this as well, and many other things, but is not available for free except for a 7 day trial). But according to its ratings (more than 4 stars), it should be a good choice.

---

For alternatives, there's [WiFi Automatic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.wifiAutoOff) which also offers to turn off WiFi e.g. when not connected for a configurable time (default: 1 minute) and to re-enable it when you're in a specified location (again identified by CellID), and also [Wi-Fi Matic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cprados.wificellmanager) which works quite similar to *Smart WiFi Toggler*. And there's my initially mentioned list for even more candidates :)

Comment: Smart Wifi Toggler worked well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can try as suggested above,
I myself use Llama Location Profiles, it also works by using the Cell IDs for location, you can set it up so it will turn off wifi when you leave home , and add conditions like BETWEEN this time frame, turn on mobile data , and when you get to work turn off mobile and turn wifi again, change your screen timeout etc.

Many phones have an included utility called smartactions or wifihelper etc